# Drawer Header Image Not filling the screen

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

so I was building a drawer inside my flutter app ( my first time using it) and then something bothers me. So when you put image in the drawer header , the image itself won't reach the top of the screen.

Picture :

[image]

And here is my code for the drawer :

```
drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/fighters.jpg")),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Menu",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 30,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

**I didn't have any padding for the code**

Please help me fix this , any help is appreciated , thank you!

Comment: Try using BoxFit.fill or fitHeight. Also, it is not wise to put drawerheader inside listview. Instead use column and then listview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
drawer: SafeArea(
    top: false,
    child: Drawer(..),
  ),
```

OR

```
MediaQuery.removePadding(
          context: context,
          removeTop: true,
          child: ListView
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but when I put that top : false in my drawer , my image still stays the same .

Comment: Woah thank you! I added that  and now the image touches the top. Thanks for your answer man !

Answer (score 0):

Use Column instead of Listview.

```
drawer: Drawer(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                DrawerHeader(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        image: AssetImage("assets/images/main_top.png")),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Menu",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 30,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
```